# Azure B2C not sending email address as input claim to REST API validation service

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to retrieve claims from a REST API service as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange. I'm trying to pass in the login email addres as an InputClaim along with another input claim (AzureTenantID). For some reason the API is always receiving the email InputClaim as empty. The other claim is populated, because it has a default value.

My understanding from the documentation is that this should work but for some reason it does not. Can anyone help me understand what I might be doing wrong? Do I have to specify a value for email?

My redacted technical profile is below. Thank you.

```
  <TechnicalProfiles>

    <!-- Custom Restful service -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-ValidateEmail">
      <DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return UserId claim</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://[servicename].azurewebsites.net/[methodname]</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <!--<Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>-->
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <!--  B2C_1A_B2cRestClientId =   WebServiceUser -->
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_B2cRestClientId" />
        <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_B2cRestClientSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="AzureTenantId" PartnerClaimType="AzureTenantId" DefaultValue="[tenant].onmicrosoft.com" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserId" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>


    <!-- Change LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail technical profile to support your validation technical profile -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserId" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-API-ValidateEmail" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>

  </TechnicalProfiles>
```

Comment: In which technical profile prior to this does the email get populated by? In the default starter pack, during sign in, the identifier is called signInName, not email.

Comment: Hi Christok. What happens when you assign a default value to email and set the AlwaysUseDefaultValue to true?

Comment: @Jas-Suri - thank you that was the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [GitHub link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-validation.md#configure-the-restful-api-technical-profile) to Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey to validate user input.

Technical profile

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidateProfile">
      <DisplayName>Check loyaltyId Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://your-account.azurewebsites.net/api/ValidateProfile?code=your-code</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loyaltyId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userLanguage" PartnerClaimType="lang" DefaultValue="{Culture:LCID}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="promoCode" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I diffed the sample technical profile against mine and nothing jumped out. It just doesn't seem like the profile is sending that email value.

Answer (score 0):

@Jas-Suri provided the correct answer in comments above. The proper claim to use in this scenario is signInName.